# SuperClass change type variable SubClass

Tags: java

I'm have a question in my projects, bellow is my class:

```
class BasePlayer {
    ...
}

class Player extend BasePlayer {
    ...
}

class BasePlayerManager {
    private List<BasePlayer> players;

    public BasePlayer getPlayerById() {

    }

    public List<BasePlayer> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }
}

class PlayerManager extend BasePlayerManager {

}
```

I need a solution in class PlayerManager. I can get as:

```
PlayerManager playerManager = new PlayerManager();
Player player = playerManager.getPlayerById();
```

Anyone can help me? I do not want to rewrite function **getPlayerById**.

Thanks you

Comment: (1) In general, this question is too vague, because you say "I need a solution" but are never really clear on what the problem is.  (2) Even though I can guess that you're looking for a way to get a "base" class to return an object of a more specific class, I still can't answer this without knowing a lot more details about the design of your project, and without knowing why you have the `Base` classes there and what you intend to do with them.  There isn't just one solution for this class of question, but you haven't given us nearly enough details.

Answer (score 0):

your questions is not in proper way, 
if your intension to get or call getPlayerById() in PlayerManager, 
you can call it directly or override the getPlayerById() since  PlayerManager is  subclass of BasePlayerManager.

Super class methods which is public or protected can call directly into subclass